# Getting values from xml using xslt

Tags: sql, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a sql stored procedure which returns the xml data.the select command of my SP is

```
SELECT TXT1 
FROM @tmp1 CT
    LEFT JOIN ETEXT TT ON CT.Cate = TT.REFKEY FOR XML AUTO
```

it returns the xml like

```
<root>
<item>
<XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B>
<TT TXT1="Mouse"/>
<TT TXT1="Computer"/>
</XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B>
</item>
</root>
```

I need to style this xml using xslt and print the TXT1 values, from last TXT1 value  to First order.I tried some code but it is not possible to get my answer .my code like

```
<xsl:variable name="cate" select="shop:ExecStoredProcedure('kt_cate',concat('@Dcat:',$default))">
    <xsl:variable name="txt1-atts" select="$cate//TT/@TXT1"/>
```

Anybody help to get my answer?

Comment: not clear what you are asking for here. Do you mean the position function?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Yes I need to select all TXT1 values from the xml from last to first means Last value Computer print first ans Mouse Print next like that

Comment: Please always provide the output that you expect to receive. I have given you an answer below, but without seeing the exact XML output, I'm left to guess.

Comment: Looks like @ABach is thinking along the same lines as I was and I've no argument with his attempt at an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's not especially clear what you're trying to accomplish - that said, if we take your comment above:

> Yes I need to select all TXT1 values from the xml from last to first
>   means Last value Computer print first ans Mouse Print next like that

...then this XSLT 1.0 solution accomplishes what you want.

**When this XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*/TT[@TXT1]">
      <xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TT">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@TXT1, '&#10;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied against the provided XML:**

```
<root>
  <item>
    <XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B>
      <TT TXT1="Mouse"/>
      <TT TXT1="Computer"/>
    </XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B>
  </item>
</root>
```

**...the wanted result is produced:**

```
Computer
Mouse
```

**Explanation:**

The XSLT is made up of two templates:

- The first template matches the first element in the document and, upon finding it, instructs the XSLT processor to apply templates to all great-grandchildren `<TT>` elements that have a `@TXT1` attribute. Most importantly, the processor is instructed to apply templates to these elements *in reverse order* (via the `<xsl:sort>` instruction).
- The second template matches all `<TT>` elements (which, given the solitary existence of the previous template, means that it will match all `<TT>` elements that have a `@TXT1` attribute). Upon finding one such element, the value of its `@TXT1` attribute is printed, followed by a newline.